# Cannot copy large file from external hard drive to hard drive

Tags: windows-xp

I have a large file on an external hard drive (about 10 GB.  Exactly 10,543,768 KB).  On my Windows XP machine, my C drive is showing me that I have 19.7 GB free.

I drag the file to my desktop and get the error: `Cannot copy some_file: There is not enough free disk space`

What gives?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some [older filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) (used when formatting a partition on a hard disk) do not allow file sizes larger than 4 GB.

It is possible your C: disk partition is formatted using FAT32, (see disk properties in Windows explorer and other places)

If so, you may be able to [convert it to NTFS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307881)